# Binary Search Tree formula for the number of structurally different trees that can exist with nodes that have either 0 or 1 children

Tags: binary-search-tree

I am trying to write a formula to find:

"The number of structurally different binary trees that can exist with nodes that have either 0 or 1 children".

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: If you're looking for a formula, that formula probably depends on some input variable. Is that *n*, the number of nodes? Or some other parameter? Also, can you define "structurally different"? Does that include mirror images or not?

Comment: Hi there, the formula depends on N which is the number of nodes. Structurally different means how many different shapes of a tree can exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that a "binary tree" that has nodes with only 0 or 1 children is a chain.  If by "structurally different" you mean that you treat differently whether a given non-terminal node has a left child or a right child, then observe that you can describe that tree with a binary number that is N-1 bits long.  So the number of different trees for a given N would be 2**N-1.

(And, obviously, if you mean how many different "shapes" of the "tree" can exist for a given N, the answer is 1.)

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer. Does 2**N-1 mean 2^N-1 or 2*N-1?

Comment: `**` is exponentiation in Fortran and several other languages.